# Node.JS OvernightJS Express CORS XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express, cors

I have an API developed in Node.JS, Typescript listening to localhost:3001
I have a frontend app in Angular, Typescript, listening to localhost:4200

I am trying to upload an image file using ngx-image-cropper, converting it to base64, from frontend to the API.

When the PATCH (update) http request is sent to the API, I get:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/member/10' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

My Overnight.JS Express server is configured as below:

const corsOpts1 = { origin: '*' };

```
this.app.use(
  cors(corsOpts1)
);
```

}

I have tried several things, no success.
For example, on top of my class controller, I added the directive ClassMiddleware as below:

@Controller('member')
@ClassMiddleware([cors()])

That's the response looking at Chrome's dev tools:

[image]

I have run out of options. My extensive research on the internet did not provide me with a successful solution.

I'd appreciate if some who had this issue before, how did you solve it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your front-end is doing a Pre-Flight cors request. Try using the following on your express server:

```
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes
```

See the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for more information (scroll down to *Enabling CORS Pre-Flight*).